# How to authenticate to a custom oAuth2 server using an existing Facebook Login ticket

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to authenticate a user from both a mobile app and a website, using a separate oAuth2 server (let say [Identityserver4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) and call it AUTHSERVER).

Both mobile app and the website have their own "Connect with Facebook" button, which uses the Facebook SDK. After a succesful Facebook login, the app/website get a Facebook ticket.

**What is the standard flow to use this ticket with the existing oAuth2 server ?**

I found this article [How to sign in user on .NET Core server after authentication on Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220193/how-to-sign-in-user-on-net-core-server-after-authentication-on-mobile-app) which does that manually using a custom API action.

I'm using dot.net core.

== EDIT ==

Finally will not use IdentityServer4, but a custom solution.

== EDIT2 ==

Found manual solution here
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: This may be helpful: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html

Comment: Well unfortunately no. This doc is for adding Facebook auth to an MVC Core app. It won't work for a mobile app for example, as the mobile app calls the FB SDK and get its own auth token from FB.